# Adding/Update Related Data ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to programming so I'm still learning.
I need to add Items to Grocery from a single view. But I can't get the data to save.
When I hit save I don't get any exceptions, the page just loads but nothing is saved to the
database. Can I get some help/guidance as to what I am doing wrong?

**Data Class**

```
  public class Grocery
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }


     public class Item {

        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**View Model**

```
public class GroceryViewModel
{
    public Grocery Grocery { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }

    public GroceryViewModel(int GroceryId)
    {
        using (var db = new MyContext())
        {
         Grocery = db.Groceries
                .Include("Items")
                .SingleOrDefault(a => a.Id == GroceryId);
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Edit(int GroceryId, GroceryViewModel groceryViewModel) 
    {
      var model = new GroceryViewModel(GroceryId);
      var plusItems = new Item
        {
            Name = groceryViewModel.Item.Name,
            Description = groceryViewModel.Item.Description,
        };

        db.Items.Add(plusItems);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction(model);
```

**View**

```
@model Project.Models.GroceryViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Groceries</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Item.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Item.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Item.Name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Item.Description)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Item.Description)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Add Item" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  using (var db = new MyContext())
  {
       var grocery = db.Groceries.Single(a => a.Id == groceryId);
       var plusItems = new Item
       {
            Name = groceryViewModel.Item.Name,
            Description = groceryViewModel.Item.Description,
       };

       grocery.Items.Add(plusItems);
       db.SaveChanges();
   }
```